# Transfer payment from paypal to paypal using paypal api without redirecting to paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I have a Paypal account that I will use to transfer payment to other website user's account where user will enter their Paypal account id and the proceed to transfer money to their(user's) account, means this process seems like freelancing websites does for Paypal withdrawal. I know Paypal provides adaptive payment method to do something like this but as per I read doc for adaptive method, seems like there is no way to do something like this through Paypal Adaptive method. I do not think to redirect user to Paypal. I would like to know the best way to do like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check Mass payment option.

It requires users email and amount to transfer. You can transfer amount from merchant account to other user account.

If provided email is registered paypal email then paypal transfer amount to that email address.

If not then user can register with that email and get money. Money will be there for one month if user not claim money with in a month then it will get refunded to merchant account.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayUsingAPI/